# How to return a filestream together with JSON model from ASPNETCore API call?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I have a controller action which is returning a file using the following line of code. However, I need return a filestream with a model which may contain some other JSON serialized data.

I've tried a few different approaches but haven't found a solution which seems to work very well. Has anyone done this before and what is considered the best approach?

```
this.File(fs, "application/zip", fileName);
```

Note: The question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069730/how-to-create-a-multipart-http-response-with-asp-net-core) is referring to multiple FileStreams, whereas I need to return back a FileStream and a Model as JSON.

However, I have modified this solution with the following. What does everyone think?

```
return new MultipartResult()
{
    new MultipartFileContent()
    {
        ContentType = "application/zip",
        FileName = fileName,
        Stream = this.OpenFile(filePath)
    },
    new MultipartModelContent()
    {
        ContentType = "application/json",
        Model = model
    }
};


public async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
{
    foreach (var item in this.OfType<MultipartFileContent>())
    {
        if (item.Stream != null)
        {
            var c = new StreamContent(item.Stream);

            if (item.ContentType != null)
            {
                c.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(item.ContentType);
            }

            if (item.FileName != null)
            {
                var contentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                contentDisposition.SetHttpFileName(item.FileName);
                c.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                c.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = contentDisposition.FileName.Value;
                c.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileNameStar = contentDisposition.FileNameStar.Value;
            }

            this.content.Add(c);
        }
    }

    foreach (var item in this.OfType<MultipartModelContent>())
    {
        var c = new ObjectContent<object>(item, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), item.ContentType);
        if (item.ContentType != null)
        {
            c.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(item.ContentType);
        }
        this.content.Add(c);
    }

    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = content.Headers.ContentLength;
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();

    await content.CopyToAsync(context.HttpContext.Response.Body);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Create a Multipart HTTP Response With ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069730/how-to-create-a-multipart-http-response-with-asp-net-core)

Comment: The duplicate I've suggested is one way you can do what you describe.

Comment: You can pass some data in HTTP headers, but some firewalls/antiviruses may wipe this data. You can also create a separate endpoint for model (`api/model/42`) and file (`api/model/42/download`). Or you can use `MultipartResult` as @john suggests (thanks john, btw).

Comment: Hey john the link you provided is very useful but is an example for returning multiple files. I'm struggling to find an example for returning a file stream and a model.