# C# .NET 6 return JSON and FILE

Tags: c#, .net

Hello is it possible to return JSON and a File at the same time?

Or have i to base64 the image and append to json?

I tried like: whats obviously is not working ->

```
return Ok(Json(jsonObject), File(memoryStreamImage, "image/jpeg"));
```

Comment: No, since you need to return single response with specific mime type. You need to create two different endpoints like GetData and GetImageForData and request it in one after another or in parallel

Comment: @AndriiKhomiak what if i am using mutlipart as response type?

Comment: Then you should search for how to create a multipart response in ASP.NET Core. I'd start with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069730

Comment: So the standard way would be to send multiple requests?