# Need to return attachment and JSON in get action method in API controller

Tags: c#, .net, api, file, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a requirement that I need to send an attachment and JSON  in a single get call.

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("IntakeByStudyIdandProjectNumber")]
        [EnableCors("LocalhostPolicy")]
        [EnableQuery]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetIntakebyStudyIdandProject()
        {
            IFormFile formFile = null;
            return ok(await _manager.GetIntakeFormByIdandName(), formFile);
        }
```

I am not sure which response type do I need to use to send both of them. For the files usually I use "FileContentResult" as the return type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create a Multipart HTTP Response With ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38069730/how-to-create-a-multipart-http-response-with-asp-net-core)